# Is there any difference on the url you use to Amazon S3 files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I noticed that there are two urls to open my files on amazon s3 buckets:

1) http://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/FOLDER/FILE.jpg

2) http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/FOLDER/FILE.jpg

Is there any difference on the way the files are accessed, charged or anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes...
Charges : See the charges http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/
Access : It will be best for you to create Bucket in that location which is near to your location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the region, there are at least 3 different ways to form a URL for an object in S3; the two you've already mentioned, plus this one:

http://bucketname.s3-xx-xxx-n.amazonaws.com/path/to/file

Here, s3-xx-xxx-n is the regional endpoint (e.g. s3-sa-east-1) for non us-standard-region buckets, or the geographic East/West s3-external-1 and s3-external-2 endpoints for US standard region buckets.

For any given bucket, they are otherwise functionally equivalent, and the pricing is the same.  One difference is that the urls beginning with the bucket name do not work with https if your bucket name has any dots in it, because of the way wildcard certificates work.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: Get request price is also different. 
For South America :GET  $0.0056 per 10,000 requests
For US: GET $0.004 per 10,000 requests

Comment: @TejKiran, I don't think you understand the question.  The way you *access* a given bucket doesn't change the region or pricing. All buckets are accessible at bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com but the absence of a regional endpoint in this url tells you nothing about the location of the bucket.  Both urls in the original question refer to the same bucket, and the bucket namespace is global, so they necessarily are in the same region, South America in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot, so there is no significant difference then, except that in the first one I don't have to specify the endpoint, and my bucket name can change the url causing https to not work.

Comment: Right, no significant difference, other than for the first few minutes after a bucket is initially created.  During this time, requests sent directly to the "s3" endpoint may issue redirects -- bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com is mapped via DNS for routing to the appropriate region for the bucket, based on where the bucket is provisioned, and the DNS changes S3 internally manages may not yet have propagated.